# Add Prefix & Suffix Values To Each String In PHP

Tags: php, string, prefix, suffix

I need to Add prefix & suffix to some values.

**Example:**

1. I'm Assigning `$value = 1234`
2. `$prefix = a`
3. `$Suffix = b`
4. The output will be like `a1ba2ba3ba4b`

May I know the procedure or sample coding in PHP?

Answer (score 3):

**You can do it like:**

```
$value = 1234;
$prefix = "a";
$suffix = "b";

// Splits every character to individual array index    
$arr = str_split($value);

$output = "";
foreach($arr AS $item)
{
    $output .= $prefix .$item.$suffix;    
}

echo $output;
```

> **[str_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)**: Convert a string to an array

Answer (score 1):

### Simple Solution using array functions

This can be done in three simple steps.

1. Separate the `$value` string to characters using a function such as [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)
2. Apply the prefix, suffix logic.
3. Join back the characters into a single `$output` string.

You can achieve this with the following snippet

**Code**

```
$value = 1234;
$prefix = "a";
$suffix = "b";

$output_ary = array_map(function($e) use ($prefix, $suffix) {
  return "{$prefix}{$e}{$suffix}";
}, str_split($value));

$output = implode($output_ary);
echo $output;
```

**Output**

```
a1ba2ba3ba4b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$s = 12345;
$a = str_split($s);

array_walk($a,"myfunction");

function myfunction($value, $key) {
    $p = 'a';
    $s = 'b';

    echo $p . $value . $s;
}
```

Output:

```
a1ba2ba3ba4ba5b
```

> [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) — Convert a string to an array
>
> [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) — Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$prefix = 'a';
$Suffix = 'b';
$value = 1234;

$str = '';
$array = str_split($value);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $str .= $prefix.$value.$Suffix;
}
print_r($str);
```